# How to match string (with regular expression) that begins with a string

Tags: regex, linux, bash

In a bash script I have to match strings that begin with exactly 3 times with the string `lo`; so `lololoba` is good, `loloba` is bad, `lololololoba` is good, `balololo` is bad.

I tried with this pattern: `"^$str1/{$n,}"`  but it doesn't work, how can I do it?

*EDIT:*

According to OPs comment, `lololololoba` is bad now.

Comment: What about `(lo){3}` ?

Comment: So more than 3 occurrences of `lo` are also good?

Comment: @anubhava I think it is but the `exactly` is confusing.

Comment: Sorry but in that moment i was in rage mode and i wrote something wrong, more than 3 is bad so "lolololoba" is not good!

Comment: ok I provided an answer to match only lines with exactly 3 `lo` at start.

Comment: I saw your comment later, added a pattern to match exactly 3 (not more than) times

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
pat="^(lo){3}"
s="lolololoba"
[[ $s =~ $pat ]] && echo good || echo bad
```

*EDIT (As per OPs comment):*

If you want to match exactly 3 times (i.e `lolololoba` and such should be unmatched):

change the `pat="^(lo){3}"` to:

```
pat="^(lo){3}(l[^o]|[^l].)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following regex :

```
^(lo){3}.*$
```

Instead of `lo` you can put your variable.

See demo https://regex101.com/r/sI8zQ6/1

Comment: No need for the `.*$` - it doesn't do anything useful. Also, while this is a valid regular expression, it's not a complete answer without showing how to use it (e.g. with `grep -E`).

Comment: Whats the point of the \1 ? Why not just match the string 3 times ?

Comment: @TomFenech Yep you are right but I wanted to give a hint instead of the complete answer!

Comment: Hmm, why not just make your answer more useful?

Comment: Also note that this will match too much, e.g. it will match `lolololoba` which OP says is bad

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` to match **exactly** 3 occurrences of `lo` at the beginning:

```
# input file
cat file
lololoba
balololo
loloba
lololololoba
lololo

# awk command to print only valid lines
awk -F '^(lo){3}' 'NF == 2 && !($2 ~ /^lo/)' file
lololoba
lololo
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment:

```
... more than 3 is bad so "lolololoba" is not good!
```

You'll find that @Jahid's answer doesn't fit (as his gives you "good" to that test string.

To use his answer with the correct regex:

```
pat="^(lo){3}(?\!lo)"
s="lolololoba"
[[ $s =~ $pat ]] && echo good || echo bad
```

This verifies that there are three "lo"s at the beginning, and not another one immediately following the three.

Note that if you're using bash you'll have to escape that `!` in the first line (which is what my regex above does)

Comment: I have added another pattern if you are interested.